# How to set my input to an already existing variable in Python?

Tags: python

I'm relatively new to python, and I can't figure out how to do this. I need to take a number input from a user, then turn that into an already existing variable. So far, I've managed to take the input, but I don't think I can make it into a variable. I am trying to turn this said input (number) to be added onto the back of a string (the string is pos)

So, for example, If I entered the number 1, i would have pos1, 2 would be pos2, so on.

```
if win == 0:
    displayboard()
    newPlot = input("")
    postochange = "pos"+newPlot
    if postochange == "X" or "O":
        print ("Sorry, but that space is taken!")
    else:
        if playerTurn == 1:
            postochange = "X"
        else:
            postochange = "O"
```

I'll try to simplify this some more, I want to have the user give me a number, that I add to the text "pos" and that corresponds to a variable that I ***already*** have.

Comment: What you’re trying to do would be better accomplished by a list or dict. Consult the online documentation.

Comment: Are you getting an error? Maybe you just need to cast newPlot to a str? `posttochange = "pos"+str(newPlot)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you instead use a dictionary of values e.g.:

```
pos_s = {'pos1':None,
         'pos2':None}

pos_s['pos'+str(user_number)] = desired_value
```

then to get the value of the variable you would do this:

`pos_s.get('pos'+str(user_number), None)`

Comment: make sure the `user_number` is a `string` not an int

Comment: This works, had to change some other stuff in the script but it works fine. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

just complementing Mason Caiby's answer, if the final user can only enter a finite collection of values, I would validate the entry with a [set](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/sets-in-python/). 
Then you can associate/correspond to a variable that you *already* have.

```
# Python program to demonstrate differences 
# between normal and frozen set 

# Same as {"a", "b","c"} 
normal_set = set(["a", "b","c"]) 

# Adding an element to normal set is fine 
normal_set.add("d") 

print("Normal Set") 
print(normal_set) 

# A frozen set 
frozen_set = frozenset(["e", "f", "g"]) 

print("Frozen Set") 
print(frozen_set) 

# Uncommenting below line would cause error as 
# we are trying to add element to a frozen set 
# frozen_set.add("h")
```